# How to avoid being detected for python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I got my code for a webscaping project:

```
c=requests.Session()
r=c.get(url, headers={header value})    

login_data={‘user’:username,’password’:pwd,’authenticity’:auth_code}

page=c.post(url, data=login_data, header={header value})
```

Then the page returns value: **looks you are trying to log in to this website from a new device**. It asked me to send confirmation.

How do I mimic my old chrome to login? anyway to avoid this warning?

Thank you

Comment: Have you ever personally logged into the web site from _that_ computer? If not, you should do it first, before you start scrapping.

Comment: yea I did, no problem logging in.. then the website detected me using a new device. How did that happen?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is nothing wrong, did you add 'User-Agent' into the headers?

```
headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0; SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0)'
    }
```

Comment: both get and post headers are the same: 
page=c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.108 Safari/537.36"})